# move items from one list to another list using sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can we move list items from list A to list B using designer 2010. I can see option to copy item but not move. I do not want to copy items.
eg. List A has 1000 iems. There is a status field.Now all items with status "sign off" should move automatically to list B. List A and List B has similar structure.

If again a user add new item in List A and owner changes status from blank to "sign off" it should also be move to List B.

Comment: quick google: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0256d5c-c058-4225-9c5e-ee544a7bba87/copying-list-items-via-manage-content-and-structure-not-copying-all-items?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 5):

There is no OOTB Move list item action.You can do this by 2 workflows one creating list item by copying and second workflow on the copied item which will delete the original list item.

This can be acheived using OOTB Sharepoint Designer workflows as well if both the lists are in same site. You have to create a List workflow and add a action "Create List Item" , configure the action to map the columns whose value needs to be same.Trigger the workflow on item updated/added  and check the Status="sign off".This way all the items in List A with status 'sign off' will be added to List B.

http://blogs.salmanghani.info/create-item-workflow-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Now in List B , create another workflow which will delete the original item from List A.Add another extra column in List B which stores ID of original copied item.Delete that ID list item from List A.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use SPD2010 and Access together.

1) In SPD, create a column (like TempID or whatever) with Number data type;

2) then, create the workflow so that if the TempID column is greater than 0, move the item from one library to another;

3) then, switch to Access. From the External Data group, import the SharePoint list.

4) Then, run a update query on the TempID column for all records changing the value to anything greater than 0. FYI, make sure there are no Required Fields in the SharePoint list.

As the field gets updated, the workflow will fire.

Takes a while, but it works.