# Move items from a custom list to another list after a specific retention

Tags: custom-list, item, retention, drop-off-library

I want to move items from a custom list with content type "item" to another list after a specific period (retention expiration).

But the transfer to another location involving drop off library supports document libraries only. Please suggest any alternatives to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a workflow to do it, copy the list item data from one list to another and then delete the current item. Then in your IRM settings, you tell it to run a workflow (that you just created).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related QA: [move items from one list to another list using sharepoint designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/move-items-from-one-list-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010)

And also I found this article on how to move items programatically: [Moving SharePoint list items to archive list](http://techno-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/10/moving-sharepoint-list-items-to-archive.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to implement and plan a retention policy for your list items, please go through following links,

http://sharepointduffbert.com/2014/07/17/using-the-information-management-policy-specifically-the-retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2011/10/12/policy-and-retention-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/10/03/applying-document-retention-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Links to external sources may break in future. Please post a summary alongside with the links. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer