# How to develop a Feature to Archive list items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, feature, archive

How to create a simple feature on SharePoint that allows the user to move an item from one list to another list, like an "Archive". It has to be a feature done through Visual Studio (C#).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move items from one list to another list using sharepoint designer 2010](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/move-items-from-one-list-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010)

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to do it. Like

- SharePoint Designer Workflow
- Remote Event recievers
- JavaScript

For your requirement follow the steps below,

[Step 1: Set Up the Visual Studio 2010 Project for the ECB Menu Item Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394512(v=office.14).aspx)

[Step 2: Create the Edit Control Block Menu Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394532(v=office.14).aspx)

[Step 3: Create a Web Application Page to Start Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394538(v=office.14).aspx)

[Step 4: Embed the code to programatically copy the files](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/programmatically-copy-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint-2010)

Refer the below blogs

[move items from one list to another list using sharepoint designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93441/move-items-from-one-list-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/programmatically-copy-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I need to do it through a SharePoint feature and on Visual Studio.

Comment: Try the above approaches

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for yet,